# Extract all occurences of a particular type in Haskell

Tags: regex, parsing, haskell, types, metaprogramming

I am writing some programs in Haskell which manipulate Haskell source code in certain ways. One of the things I would like to be able to do is to extract all occurrences of a particular type (and possibly their positions as well).

I figured a very crude method using regular expressions would work for simple data types. For example, in the following graphics code:

```
module Test where
    import Picture

    r1,r2,r3,r4 :: Region
    r1 = Shape(Rectangle 2 2)
    r2 = Shape(Ellipse 2 1.5)
    r3 = Shape(RtTriangle 3 2)
    r4 = Shape(Polygon [(-2.5, 2.5), (-3.0,0), (-1.7,-1.0), (-1.1,0.2),(-1.5,2.0)])

    p1,p2,p3,p4 :: Picture
    p1 = Region Red r1
    p2 = Region Green r2
    p3 = Region Blue r3
    p4 = Region Yellow r4

    pic :: Picture
    pic = foldl Over EmptyPic [p1,p2,p3,p4]
```

I could extract every number by simply creating a regular expression which looks for every instance of numeric characters with no letters surrounding them. Likewise If I wanted to find all colours, I could hard code a regular expression which searches for occurrences of Red or Green or Blue... etc.

The problems as I see it with this method are:

1. If I ever want to change the type I am searching for, I have to hard code every possible way that type could manifest itself
2. It doesn't work if the type value is returned as the result of a function call. For example, if p1 instead read:

   p1 = Region (getColor 1) r1

where:

```
getColor :: Int -> Color
getColor n
    |n == 1 = Red
    |otherwise = Green
```

Is there a more general way to parse a Haskell file so as to extract all occurrences of a particular type and, if possible, their positions within the text of the source file?

Comment: I'm sure you can do something with http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src

Comment: @Bergi So it seems like this library would allow me to convert my source code into an abstract syntax tree, which I could then search for occurences of a particular type. There doesnt seem to be any sort of way to map between the source text structure and the AST structure however (Which I would need to find out *where* each occurence of the type actually was in the source). Is there a way to preserve at least line numbers or something?

Answer (score 7):

You can use a parser, namely [haskell-src-exts](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell-src-exts/1.13.5/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Exts-Parser.html), which preserves position information (line and column numbers) in the output AST.

Comment: This is useful, but from what I can see, using a parsing function like parseModule from haskell-src-ext gives only minimal source information (i.e the line and column numbers of function definitions and function type definitions. It does not give information on constructors or values mentioned within a function. Am I missing something / Is there a way to extend this slightly further to do what I want?

Comment: >  It does not give information on constructors or values mentioned    -- you are looking for a static analysis pass, which you will need to do /after/ parsing. There are no libraries for this, beyond you manipulating the AST returned by the parser.